# Assert multiple Id's using for loop in selenium and python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I want to assert all ids in the list with for loop, my code is not working:

```
list = ["'block-views-news_of_the_day-block_1'", "'views_slideshow_singleframe_main_carousal_new_block-block_1-2'",
            "'block-views-recent_contents-block_1'","'block-views-recent_contents-block_2'","'block-views-home_page_events-block_1'",
            "'const-cont-home","block-block-13'", "'block-block-58'"]

for x in list:
self.assertTrue(self.driver.find_element_by_id(x))
```

Error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx\Selenium Scripts\xxxr\TestCases.py", line 50, in
>   test_flush_cache
>       self.assertTrue(self.driver.find_element_by_id(x))
>    File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 266, in find_element_by_id 
>       return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
>    File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 744, in find_element
>       {'using': by, 'value': value})['value'] 
>    File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 233, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response) 
>    File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 194, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) 
>  selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
>   locate element:
>   {"method":"id","selector":"'block-views-news_of_the_day-block_1'"}

Comment: where its get failed?Can you share error pls

Comment: Error updated above

Comment: Be careful of what assert are you are using, check what find_element_by_id returns, if returns true or object if the element is found.

Answer (score 1):

Using single quotes inside of double quotes seems weird/wrong. So first thing would be to remove those.

Then if one of the elements from the list doest exist you will get a NoSuchElementException. If you want the test to fail instead of just having an exception in your script you should handle this exception. I would write this test like this:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

ids = [
    "block-views-news_of_the_day-block_1",
    "views_slideshow_singleframe_main_carousal_new_block-block_1-2",
    "block-views-recent_contents-block_1",
    "block-views-recent_contents-block_2",
    "block-views-home_page_events-block_1",
    "const-cont-home","block-block-13",
    "block-block-58"
]

for id in ids: 
    try:
        self.driver.find_element_by_id(id)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        self.fail()
```

In this case test will fail when one element is missing from the page and wont check for others. If you want to keep checking for other elements you need to have a list where you collect missing elements instead of `self.fail()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the double or single quotes, something like:

```
list = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
```

or

```
list = ["id1", "id2", "id3"]
```

As you see in the last line it includes the single quotes as part of the id and that results in an error.

Comment: Thanks for the Code can you Help with a Code for If you want to keep checking for other elements you need to have a list where you collect missing elements instead of self.fail(). also as it is not Clear from Context

Comment: You need to use a concept like soft assert, find an assert library that has this or implement it yourself by checking in with an if and add it to a fail list if false.. and at the end assert that the list is empty.